# Press "R" to restart (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, restart

I need help with my script. Currently, it works fine to restart the level, however if the player holds the "r" key, the game will reload every frame, which causes it to glitch and crash on some systems.

How would I go about altering my script to prevent this issue?

Thank you!

- David

Here is my current script.

```
public void Update()
    {   // Reset game on "r" press
         if (!levelIsComplete)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1f;

                Retry();
            }
    }

public void Retry()
    {
        //Restarts current level
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a `GetKeyPress` instead of `GetKeyDown`?  (Apologies, I'm not a Unity programmer).  The reason I ask is because there are two primary events on a Key Press.  `Key Down` and `Key Up`.  A Key Press can be considered both of these events combined, thus only restarting the game after it is pressed, rather than when the Key is held Down.

Comment: Change the event to `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R)`, and it will restart once the button has been released.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate script and attach to to a different game object.

Mark it as [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

```
public class Reloader : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method and it returned the same result

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the button is pushed if so then dont let it be called again.

```
public class restartGame: MonoBehaviour {
    bool restart;
    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        restart = false;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && !restart) {
            restart = true;  
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}
```

or use `Input.GetKeyUp` which is called when the button is released

```
   void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R) && !restart) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool canRestart = false;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && canRestart)
        {
            canRestart = false;
            Restart();
        }

    }
    private void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```